# any good javascript library for cross-browser & printer friendly pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am working on a web project where we have to come up with "a cross-browser & printer-friendly solution".

The markup is complex enough but after a few hours I managed to come up with something pretty enough on Chrome using CSS only (with media="print" dedicated stylesheet).

However, after testing it on Firefox (18.0.2) & IE9, I realize that only starting to realize where I got myself into. Firefox only prints the 1st page, and not even properly, it's messy. IE9 prints it all but it looks horrible.

After googling and SOing for some time, I quickly realized that printing web pages using browser's built in print support is rather at an experimental state. Probably fine for neat HTML pages but 90% of the internet is probably not neat HTML pages, anyhow, that's another debate.

So, I am wondering if there is any javascript library that "does the job" ?

I have come across these projects but I'm unsure if this would do the trick:

- http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf
- http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look into CSS media queries instead?

Comment: "printer-friendly" - what does JS have to do with that, left alone that buttons won't be interactive on paper? Look into CSS!

Comment: You know, I've run into this with the need for customers to print payment confirmations, and I wanted them to look nice - cross platform.  The CSS route was always finicky especially when it came to IE6.  The route I went with was PHP PDF creation.  The reason was I could guarantee that it would print the same (pretty much) whether on Mac, Windows, Linux, Firefox, IE Chrome etc ... And the customer could save the file if they wanted a digital copy for their records...  It's just a thought.

Comment: Consider opening a new page with the printable content with print styles applied.

Comment: @mika: yes, that's what I first used (see amended question)

Comment: @Bergi: I ran into issues when using CSS (see amended question)

Comment: Before asking that question - that I believe is a very relevant question as the HTML/CSS world is huge - I probably should have read this http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: I had all my stylesheets with media="all" & my print stylesheet with media="print", so when rendering for printing, all the stylesheets + the "print" stylesheets were merged. This was causing the issue. Turning all other stylesheets to media="screen" did the trick. Loads of styling to do now but at least I can have a kind of "easy" cross-browser solution