# Some questions on print functionality on browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser, printing

I have some very basic questions related to the print functionality across browsers. When we do `ctrl + P` or call `window.print()` from javascript, it opens a print dialog which is different for different browsers. Can this print dialog be customizable? can we add some custom functionality to this dialog using javascript? Do we have some document which explains the print functionality across browsers in detail?

Comment: They will flag this like they flagged this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14963128/1267304

Comment: Start by looking at [MDN's information on print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing).  I would expect that you can't modify the dialogs, but you can at least call set up handlers using `window.onbeforeprint` and `window.onafterprint`, but [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#handler-window-onbeforeprint) doesn't specify much of what they have to do (and they're not in every browser!).  Can you make your own dialog to create a pdf, then let the user view/save the pdf and go from there?  That gives cross browser functionality, but is a lot of work.